# How to resolve IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, arraylist

i've just recived java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: but can't understand what its caused from. Basically, i am integrating records of sqlite table into listview.
Here is my sql query to fetch records from the table.

```
public ArrayList<Integer> getRecordsCount(int no) {

    ArrayList<Integer> count = new ArrayList<>();

    Cursor c = database.rawQuery(
            "select count(*) as TotalCount, tDate, " +
                    "strftime('%d', tDate) as DayPart, " +
                    "strftime('%m', tDate) as MonthPart, " +
                    "strftime('%Y', tDate) as YearPart " +
                    "from library " +
                    "where type = '" + no + "' " +
                    "group by MonthPart, YearPart", null);

    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        count.add(c.getInt(0));
    }

    return count;
}
```

This is my method to retrieve that data :-

```
public void setDataInList(int no) {

    if (no == 0) {

        ArrayList<Integer> count = helper.getRecordsCount(1);

        mainGetLibraryModels.clear();
        MainLibraryModelWS modelWS = helper.getAllRecordsMonthWise2(no);
        for (int i = 0; i < modelWS.getRecords().size(); i++) {

            WSLibraryModel model = new WSLibraryModel();
            model.setAmount(modelWS.getRecords().get(i).getAmount());
            model.setTotalCount("" + count.get(i));
            model.setYearPart(modelWS.getRecords().get(i).getYearPart());
            model.setMonthPart(modelWS.getRecords().get(i).getMonthPart());

            mainGetLibraryModels.add(model);

        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    } else if (no == 1) {

        ArrayList<Integer> count = helper.getRecordsCount(2);

        mainGetLibraryModels.clear();
        MainLibraryModelWS modelWS = helper.getAllRecordsMonthWise2(no);
        for (int i = 0; i < modelWS.getRecords().size(); i++) {

            WSLibraryModel model = new WSLibraryModel();
            model.setAmount(modelWS.getRecords().get(i).getAmount());
            model.setTotalCount("" + count.get(i));
            model.setYearPart(modelWS.getRecords().get(i).getYearPart());
            model.setMonthPart(modelWS.getRecords().get(i).getMonthPart());

            mainGetLibraryModels.add(model);
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    } else {

        mainGetLibraryModels.clear();
        MainLibraryModelWS modelWS = helper.getAllRecordsMonthWise2(no);
        for (int i = 0; i < modelWS.getRecords().size(); i++) {

            WSLibraryModel model = new WSLibraryModel();
            model.setAmount(modelWS.getRecords().get(i).getAmount());
            model.setTotalCount(" - ");
            model.setYearPart(modelWS.getRecords().get(i).getYearPart());
            model.setMonthPart(modelWS.getRecords().get(i).getMonthPart());

            mainGetLibraryModels.add(model);

        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
 }
```

But, when i run this code, it gives me this error?

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.teezom, PID: 14168
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
```

Comment: Because count array size is 1 so you need to access by 0 index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all use `switch` instead of `if-else` branching , because what i see your Result from query will give the fix number of result as an array (switch is more efficient and improve readability) .

```
public void setDataInList(int no) {  //just a suggestion not a answer

  switch (no){
     case 0 :   
          //Your Code as you specified in your code context.
           break;
     case 1 :
          //Your Code as you specified in your code context.

          break;
     case 2 :
          //Your Code as you specified in your code context.

         break;
    default :
         break;
   }
```

Now Coming to your problem if you see your `Exception` StackTrace and debug the application once you will get your solution easily.

> this is what your stacktrace says--

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
```

Hope you know this popular exception `IndexOutOfBoundsException` only came while you try to access the any array index which is not present in array.

Now your error message clearly said that your `Array` size is `one`. It means your array will only accessible to index `zero` (0).

So, Please debug your code and try to find out which line of code is generating exception in-fact

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this :

```
ArrayList<Integer> count = helper.getRecordsCount(1);
```

Try this :

```
ArrayList<Integer> count = helper.getRecordsCount(0);
```

Comment: No, I can't. I am getting records using that no

Comment: @MaheshBpsk To access element at first position you should access element at 0. Index starts from 0. You are checking if (no == 0) and sending 1 to access the record. and in second if instead of 2 put 1.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to avoid calling getRecords() so many times. It costs performance and might not be returning the same result - the possible reason for your error. Instead, introduce a local parameter as a cache output of this function and play with it.

Comment: This should have been a comment. Also you did not actually answer the question asked by the OP.

Comment: My reputation < 50. I wish I could...